# How do I play an m4a file in swift 2 upon the touch of a button?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swift2

How do I play an audio file when I touch a button, nothing is working that i can find online because its all swift 1.

I want the audio code in the `original` function.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func original(sender: AnyObject) {        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is some code to get you going:

**Swift 3**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    let player = AVQueuePlayer()

    @IBAction func original(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample_song", withExtension: "m4a") {
            player.removeAllItems()
            player.insert(AVPlayerItem(url: url), after: nil)
            player.play()
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    let player = AVQueuePlayer()

    @IBAction func original(sender: AnyObject) {
        if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("SomeAudioFile", withExtension: "m4a") {
            player.removeAllItems()
            player.insertItem(AVPlayerItem(URL: url), afterItem: nil)
            player.play()
        }
    }
}
```

You did not explain what should happen if the button is hit multiple times, so I assumed that you would want to stop the current item being played and start a new one.

Comment: If we put "mp3" extension it works for .mp3 files. 
Strange thing playing m4a files with Swift 5... any suggestions?)

Answer (score 1):

```
if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("SomeAudioFile", withExtension: "m4a") {
            player.removeAllItems()
            player.insertItem(AVPlayerItem(URL: url), afterItem: nil)
            player.play()
        } else {

print("Go to your Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources to make sure that your music file IS INDEED there. If not, drag it from the Navigator pane into the Copy Bundle Resources folder.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5 update:

```
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SomeAudioFile", withExtension: "m4a") {
        player.removeAllItems()
        player.insert(AVPlayerItem(url: url), after: nil)
        player.play()
    }
```