# Some M4A files are not streaming

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, m4a

I am using freestreamer library in my ios app
https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer

Some of the m4a files stream but some did not , return an error with an invalid format , But that files stream on website as well as other website also. And when i download the file it plays on every player .

Few links which is not streaming:

1 -  http://ec2-35-160-200-201.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/media/Company/Gaming%2020160425%20MS%20Sony%20Top%20Pick.m4a

2 -  http://ec2-35-160-200-201.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/media/Company/Lenovo%2020160510%20MS%20Downgrade%20To%20Sell.m4a

Comment: try this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068559/how-do-i-play-an-m4a-file-in-swift-2-upon-the-touch-of-a-button
hope it will help you

Comment: please note, this link opens it from local storage. I need to stream the m4a. Apparently, its some "header" issue in some m4a files, i dont know whether its a flac or alac, something to do with it. cant find a universal player...